# TensorflowJs says - 'Error: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `inputShape` or `batchInputShape` argument.' while loading the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I created a UNet Model in Tensorflow on my python environment and saved it using tfjs by tfjs.converters.save_keras_model()

The model summary is given below.

```
Model: "model_4"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 256, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_43 (Sequential)      (None, 128, 128, 64) 3072        input_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_44 (Sequential)      (None, 64, 64, 128)  131584      sequential_43[1][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_45 (Sequential)      (None, 32, 32, 256)  525312      sequential_44[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_46 (Sequential)      (None, 16, 16, 512)  2099200     sequential_45[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_47 (Sequential)      (None, 8, 8, 512)    4196352     sequential_46[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_48 (Sequential)      (None, 4, 4, 512)    4196352     sequential_47[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_49 (Sequential)      (None, 2, 2, 512)    4196352     sequential_48[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_50 (Sequential)      (None, 1, 1, 512)    4196352     sequential_49[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_51 (Sequential)      (None, 2, 2, 512)    4196352     sequential_50[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_16 (Concatenate)    (None, 2, 2, 1024)   0           sequential_51[0][0]              
                                                                 sequential_49[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_52 (Sequential)      (None, 4, 4, 512)    8390656     concatenate_16[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_17 (Concatenate)    (None, 4, 4, 1024)   0           sequential_52[0][0]              
                                                                 sequential_48[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_53 (Sequential)      (None, 8, 8, 512)    8390656     concatenate_17[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_18 (Concatenate)    (None, 8, 8, 1024)   0           sequential_53[0][0]              
                                                                 sequential_47[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_54 (Sequential)      (None, 16, 16, 512)  8390656     concatenate_18[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_19 (Concatenate)    (None, 16, 16, 1024) 0           sequential_54[0][0]              
                                                                 sequential_46[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_55 (Sequential)      (None, 32, 32, 256)  4195328     concatenate_19[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_20 (Concatenate)    (None, 32, 32, 512)  0           sequential_55[0][0]              
                                                                 sequential_45[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_56 (Sequential)      (None, 64, 64, 128)  1049088     concatenate_20[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_21 (Concatenate)    (None, 64, 64, 256)  0           sequential_56[0][0]              
                                                                 sequential_44[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_57 (Sequential)      (None, 128, 128, 64) 262400      concatenate_21[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_22 (Concatenate)    (None, 128, 128, 128 0           sequential_57[0][0]              
                                                                 sequential_43[1][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_26 (Conv2DTran (None, 256, 256, 3)  6147        concatenate_22[0][0]             
==================================================================================================
Total params: 54,425,859
Trainable params: 54,414,979
Non-trainable params: 10,880
```

When I check model.input_shape it outputs - (None, 256, 256, 3)

So, the model has the input shape defined but while loading it in the tfjs, the error says that the first layer of Sequential should have input_shape or batch_input_shape

When I check the model.json after conversion from tfjs, it has the following config for first Input Layer

```
"config": 
    {
        "batch_input_shape": [null, 256, 256, 3],
        ...
```

So, what should I do in order to load the model in TensorFlowJS on the browser?

Comment: Instead of using an InputLayer, can you just use the input_shape of the first sequential layer. Could you please add your python model to the question ?

Comment: I tried doing that, but it gave the same error. The model is made up of many sequential layers with individual layers in it, as you can see from the model.summary(). So, I tried manually defining input_shape to every sequential layer and it worked. Thank you for the response!